# How can I create a <a href=> to facebook and share a message?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, templates

I don't want to share my PAGE, but I want to share a message with a short URL link to something.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you're talking about this, right?

> http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&t=Google

It will let you share "www.google.com" on Facebook using the title "Google". All encoded, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Facebook API stream.publish function:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish

or FB.Connect.streamPublish:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish

Comment: Both of those require extended permissions. You can use <fb:share-button> (FBML or XFBML) which does not require the extended permissions because they run on the facebook server and enlist the users interaction to publish.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very easy way to do it: http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/share.php